# Where are the other solutions to this ODE disappearing in this analysis?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

I am asked to solve the following ODE involving constants $\alpha, L, V_0 > 0$ and $E < 0$:

$$-\psi'' - \alpha V_0\psi\cdot [\delta(x)+\delta(x-L)] = \alpha E\psi.$$

In particular, we want solutions $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ that are:

- Continuous
- $L^2$

We are given that the solutions look something like this (shifted):

[image]

Now pretend we didn't know this. Here is my attempt at arriving at these functions:

> Away from $0$ and $L$, the ODE is just the wave equation, whose solutions are always of the form $a_1e^{-i\sqrt{\alpha E}x}+a_2e^{i\sqrt{\alpha E}x}.$ So we know $\psi$ is also of this form piece-wise:
>   $$\psi(x)=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
>     A_1e^{\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x}+A_2e^{-\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x} & x<0 \\
>     B_1e^{\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x}+B_2e^{-\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x} & 0\leq x< L \\
>     C_1e^{\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x} & x\geq  L \\
> \end{array} \right.$$
>   (I expanded a little here, since $E<0\Rightarrow \sqrt{\alpha E}=i\sqrt{|\alpha E|}$)
>
> - For $\psi$ to be integrable, we also need the exponentials with infinite > support be integrable. Then $A_2=C_1=0.$
>
> Then we can simplify it:
>   $$\psi(x)=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
>     A_1e^{\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x} & x<0 \\
>     B_1e^{\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x}+B_2e^{-\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x} & 0\leq x< L \\
>     C_2e^{-\sqrt{|\alpha E|}x}& x\geq L \\
> \end{array} \right.$$
>   All that's left to do is to find the space of coefficients $A_i,B_i,C_i$ so that it is continuous and satisfies the DE.
>
> - For $\psi$ to be continuous, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\psi(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\psi(x)$ and likewise at $L$. So $A_1=B_1+B_2,$ and a similar equation at $L.$
> - To satisfty the ODE at $0$ and $L$, because of the deltas, we know that the derivative must have a discintinuity of size $-\alpha V_0 \psi$ there. In particular: $(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\psi'(x))-(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\psi'(x))=-\alpha V_0 \psi(0),$ so computing these terms, $(\sqrt{|\alpha E|}B_1 - \sqrt{|\alpha E|}B_2)- (\sqrt{|\alpha E|}A_1) = -\alpha V_0A_1$. We have a similar equation at $L$.

Now we have 4 equations relating all the coefficients to each other. I solved this system and plotted the solutions. The problem is, varying values of $\alpha, L, V_0, E$, I can only get solutions that look like the 'even' graph.

Where did the odd solutions disappear in this analysis and how do you get them back?

Comment: Your calculations seem ok, although I think that you are missing a factor $\alpha$ in the last $V_0 A_1$ (there should be no $A_2$ neither here or just above and no $B_3$). It seems quite clear that there should be an 'odd' solution. So not obvious why you don't get it?

Comment: The ode is of second order. Why the three constants? There is no constant solution to the harmonic oscillator other than the zero solution.

Comment: In fact it could be the (wrong) presence of $B_3$ which mislead Sage. The system is (wrongly)  underdetermined and sage picks a non-zero value of $B_3$ which makes the solution look 'even'?

Comment: I found an error in the post. $A_3 = B_3 = C_3=0$ not for integrability concerns but because for $x\neq 0,a$ $\psi$ has to be an eigenfunction of the second derivative operator, which those are not.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh, Whoops, fixed. thanks. My best guess is that the odd solution comes out under appropriate conditions on $L,V_0$ that makes the system degenerate. Right now the system of equations in matrix form is full-rank.

Comment: @SeanLake Nice, thanks I see this now. I'll try again without $B_3$...

Comment: @enthdegree The presence of this constant is letting the eigenvalue $E$ roam free.

Comment: This system of equations should solve it, but sagecloud stalls on it: http://pastebin.com/rqZph3aP $${}$$ I expect there to be two degrees of freedom. I expected this to be simpler since the system is linear...

Comment: Keep in mind that the normalization is not fixed by this equation, so you still have one unfixed degree of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the solution to the ODE is
$$
\psi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
A_1 e^{\sqrt{-\alpha E} x} & x < 0,\\
B_1 e^{\sqrt{-\alpha E} x} + B_2 e^{-\sqrt{-\alpha E} x} & 0 < x < L, \\
C_2 e^{-\sqrt{-\alpha E} x} & L < x.\\
\end{cases}
$$
Writing the jump and continuity conditions in matrix form, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & e^{2 L \sqrt{-\alpha E}} & 1 & -1\\
1-\sqrt{-\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{E}} & -1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & e^{2 L \sqrt{-\alpha E}} & -1 & 1-\sqrt{-\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{E}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\ B_1 \\ B_2 \\ C_2\end{pmatrix} = 0,
$$
so either you have the trivial solution or the determinant of the matrix is zero. Hence,
$$
f(E) = e^{2 L\sqrt{-\alpha E}}\left(1 - \frac{4 E}{\alpha V_0^2} - 4\sqrt{-\frac{E}{\alpha V_0^2}}\right) = 1.
$$
This is an interesting equation. It's clear that is trivially satisfied if $E = 0$, but this leads to a nonphysical solution.

The function $f$ is nonnegative, has a unique double root at $E = -\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{4}$ and grows as $c_1|E|e^{c_2\sqrt{|E|}}$. This means that it exists at least one solution  of the transcendental equation such that $f(E_*) = 1$. Moreover,

$$-\alpha V_0^2 < E_* < -\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{4}.$$

Also, if $\alpha V_0 L > 2$, then $$\lim_{E\to 0^-}f'(E) = -\infty,$$ wich implies that $f$ has a local maximum $E_M$  such that $f(E_M) > 1$, i.e., 
$$E_M = -\tfrac{(\alpha V_0 L - 2)^2}{4 \alpha L^2}.$$
As consequence, there is a second solution such that $f(E^*) = 1$, where 
$$-\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{4} < E^* < -\tfrac{(\alpha V_0 L - 2)^2}{4 \alpha L^2}.$$

Combining this results, we have:

> **Lemma.** If $0 < \alpha V_0 L \le 2$, there exist one eigenvalue, $$-\alpha V_0^2 < E_* < -\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{4}.$$ If $2 < \alpha V_0 L$, there exist two eigenvalues, $$-\alpha V_0^2 < E_* < -\frac{\alpha V_0^2}{4} < E^* < -\tfrac{(\alpha V_0 L - 2)^2}{4 \alpha L^2}.$$

For $L=1$, $\alpha = 1$, $V_0 = \frac{3}{2}$, this is how the eigenfunction looks like:
[image]

For $L=1$, $\alpha = 1$, $V_0 = \frac{5}{2}$, this are the two eigenfunctions:
[image]

Nice!